# Drawing axis with depth

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to make an axis with depth and I am kinda stuck. First I've tried drawing on canvas but it would not be best option - handling responsivity from scratch is pretty hard. Then I've realised that I can do this using CSS and perspective using [cube shape codepen](https://codepen.io/amit_sheen/pen/44b2c7661a9db555a5714322dd129657)

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #eee;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
  perspective: 800px;
  -webkit-perspective-origin: top right;
  perspective-origin: top right;
}

.cube {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.side {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.9;
  border: 2px solid white;
}

.front {
  background-color: #d50000;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(100px);
  transform: translateZ(100px);
}

.back {
  background-color: #aa00ff;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-100px);
  transform: translateZ(-100px);
}

.left {
  background-color: #304ffe;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(100px);
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(100px);
}

.right {
  background-color: #0091ea;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
}

.top {
  background-color: #00bfa5;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(100px);
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(100px);
}

.bottom {
  background-color: #64dd17;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="cube">
    <div class="side front"></div>
    <div class="side left"></div>
    <div class="side right"></div>
    <div class="side back"></div>
    <div class="side top"></div>
    <div class="side bottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I only need is to remove not needed sides, but again, I've realised that I would need to handle flexible dimensions, like width != height etc. Could any body give me a hint or example how to implement simple axis where inside might be image present?

[image]

Comment: _"I only need is to remove not needed sides"_. Not sure what you mean, _hidden faces_? Just the borders without background?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti yeah, I can remove them from DOM. Only 
    <div class="side right"></div> and <div class="side front"></div> will left and perespective will be about -40%

Comment: I'm really not sure what the final result should be but: your faces now have opacity 0.9. Without opacity they'll nicely _hide_ partially obstructed axes

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti the result should be as it's at the included image. For given width, height and depth I need to draw an axis. Based on the codepen example I can create axis by adding borders to right and top side and removing background :D, but it will not work for different dimension than width === height === depth